# ios Getting Location react-native/Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, location, expo

I am building an app totally depending on the users location, the app takes latitude and longitude of the user and depends on that retrieve the data for user

The app is working well with android but with ios is not getting the location of the user

any possible solution or something might be missed ?

and this is my code .... and this is the error

**[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Cannot obtain current location: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"]**

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

const getLocation = dispatch => async () => {
    let {status} = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status === !'granted') {
        dispatch({type: 'add_error' , error : 'Permission to access location denied'});
    }
    navigate('Home');

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

    dispatch({type : 'get_location' , payload : location});   
    dispatch({type : 'lat_value', payload : location.coords.latitude});
    dispatch({type : 'long_value', payload : location.coords.longitude});



    let keys = {
        latitude : location.coords.latitude,
        longitude : location.coords.longitude        
    }


    await AsyncStorage.setItem('lat', JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude));
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('lng', JSON.stringify(location.coords.longitude));


    const place = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(keys, 'en');
        place.find( p => {
            stateName =
             p.region + ' ';

            area = p.city;
            country = p.country;
        });
        dispatch({type : 'set_country', payload: place.country});      
        dispatch({type: 'area' , payload : area});
```

Comment: Do you explicitly need GPS? Or network will be enough to get an estimated location?

Comment: Also, try using try-catch block

Comment: actually I need latitude and longitude as my api fetch depends on them. that's why I need to get the location